# Changing encryption in pkcs12 file from RC2-40-CBC to AES-256-CBC using openssl

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

as title says, I'm trying to change the encryption of the private key contained within an pkcs12 file from RC2-40-CBC to AES-256-CBC using openssl 3.0

I tried

`openssl pkcs12 -legacy  -in cert.p12 -out temp.pem -nodes`

`openssl pkcs12 -export  -in temp.pem -out new.p12 -aes256`

But it tells me that aes256 is ignored... any hints?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [manpage of openssl-pkcs12](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html), you will find that `-aes256` is defined as a `PKCS#12 input (parsing) options`, meaning that it is only used when reading an existing PKCS#12 file.
In this case, it is used to encrypt the private key that is contained within it.

In your case, using the `-export` switch, you rather want to create a new PKCS#12 container. Unfortunately, the command line options to chose the cipher for this mode of operation are not as easy to use. Apart from  `-descert` and `-legacy`, both of which should really not be used as they defer to outdated algorithm, you can only use `-keypbe` and `-certpbe` alongside a specification string.

On the bright side, any modern version of openssl whould use AES-CBS as the default encryption algorithm for new containers, so just drop the aes switch and you should be fine.

Here is a short demo, including verification of the alogrithm used, on a current Debian Testing system:

```bash
$ openssl req -new -x509  -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -subj "/CN=Test" -nodes

$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out test.p12                             
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:

$ openssl pkcs12 -info -in test.p12
Enter Import Password:
MAC: sha256, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 32, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 4B 13 3A 4A 34 2E A4 38 62 E0 1C CB 83 6D D7 5D 7B 9C FB EC 
subject=CN = Test
issuer=CN = Test
[...]

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023)
```

If you are one an older version of openssl, which doesn't use AES by default, you can try using the following explicit command:

```bash
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out test.p12 -keypbe aes-256-cbc -certpbe aes-256-cbc
```